# How would a species with crustacean-like "mouths" sound when speaking?

Tags: aliens, language

What might their language sound like? Would they have any speech impediments to contend with speaking a Common language?

Comment: As the current answer shows, you need to define what you mean by "mouth."  Is it where the crustacean takes in air?  Water?  (Remember that many live underwater and don't breathe air at all).  Food?  Humans breathe air through their mouths (as well as noses) and eat and drink through the same orifice.  But that's not required.  You need to define your crustaceans and their "mouths" better.

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!  We're glad you could join us!  When you have a moment, please [click here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388) to learn more about our culture and take our [tour].  This question is unclear.  Do you have a specific breed of shrimp, crab, lobster, barnacle, or other critter you're thinking of?  Sound is only partially defined by the shape and capacity of the mouth.  What are you thinking of in terms of larynx and vocal chords?  How large is this creature?  Can you give us its physiology?  Thanks!

Comment: If the creature speaks through its mouth, then it has a different range of sounds than that of humans: having no lips, it cannot make many sounds dependent on them. All sounds come from the vocal cords and maybe the tongue. Birds have a rigid mouth (the beak) and make such sounds.

Comment: A truly refined and sophisticated crustacean would not be so crass as to point out *our* speech impediment(s).

Answer (score 4):

Since crustaceans don't pass air through their mouths, the most you could expect sound wise from the mouth would be clicking, grinding, and rasping (like crickets). To form vowels you need a shapeable resonant cavity with a shapeable opening and a source of vibration to modulate. Crustaceans are simply not equipped that way.